# Is an implementation of TextBlock for usage of the TextDecorations property via Style possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

We are working with WPF in VS 2015 and want to implement the TextDecorations-property in the following controls:
- Button
- Checkbox
- Label
- RadioButton

One way is to implement a TextBlock-control as the Content like that:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkbox">
    <TextBlock>
        CheckBox<Run TextDecorations="Underline"></Run>
    </TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```

Then - in the code - it would be possible to adjust the property:

```
FrameworkElement fe = this.checkbox;
if (fe.GetType().GetProperty("Content") != null && fe.GetType().GetProperty("Content").GetValue(fe).GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
{
    FrameworkElement tbb = (FrameworkElement)fe.GetType().GetProperty("Content").GetValue(fe);
    tbb.GetType().GetProperty("TextDecorations").SetValue(tbb, TextDecorations.Underline);
}
```

But what we really want is an implementation via a style like that example:

```
<Style x:Key="checkboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="container">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="display"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                       Margin="5,2,5,2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is this possible and does someone know an example for it?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Comment: Will ir work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not exactly what we wanted. We need to implement a TextBlock inside a Checkbox (per example), so that we are able to set the TextDecorations-property at runtime.

Comment: You are not clear.  Will you pls update your exact goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! We had a little mistake here.

Comment: It will be nice if you share the solution so that others can make use of it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `TextDecorations="Underline"` in your `TextBlock` on `ControlTemplate`

```
<TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" x:Name="display" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="5,2,5,2"/>
```